# validating between from and To date using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have two datetime pickers in a form, one for From date and one for End date. The user may select only the current date or the next date as the From date. For example, if today is 28th April, then user may select the 28th or 29th only. If the user selects the other dates, they should get an alert saying "Invalid". How can I add JavaScript validation to do this?

Comment: are you using jquery datepicker? can you provide some code?

Comment: I am not using jquery datepicker i am doing the datepicker in html

Comment: so provide your custom code to let us have a look at it.

Comment: when i select date from datepicker it is of this format 28-04-2014 05:33AM

Comment: are you using HTML5 `input type="date"` ?

Comment: no I am using from my framework

Comment: is there no attributes like `min` date in your framework datepicker ?

Comment: no i dnt know about it

Comment: can you post your datepicker ?

Comment: Date: text box Pick a date

Comment: while selecting date from picker it appears in this format 28-04-2014 05:33 AM

Answer (score 0):

```
function DateDiff(date1, date2) {
    date1.setHours(0);
    date1.setMinutes(0, 0, 0);
    date2.setHours(0);
    date2.setMinutes(0, 0, 0);
    var datediff = Math.abs(date1.getTime() - date2.getTime()); // difference 
    var diff = parseInt(datediff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000), 10) 
    if(diff>1 )
        alert("invalid dates");        
}

DateDiff(new Date("2012-12-12"), new Date("2012-12-14"));
```

`Fiddle`: http://jsfiddle.net/wjW66/2/

Comment: but it should allow only current and next day

Comment: you mean to say the user can only select 12/12/1984 and 12/13/1984 in the end date field. right?

Comment: yes thats right if the user selects start and end date then it should be only 12/12/1984 or 13/12/1984 for both start and end dates

Comment: @user13763: check the updated answer, according to you it should now take 12 and 13 but not greater than 12 and 13.

Comment: can u please explain i am very new to javascript

Comment: also what is 864e5 which u posted before

Comment: @user13763: is this code working as per your requirement?. 1000*60*60*24 or 86400000 or 864e5 is a valid JavaScript number that represents the number of seconds in a 24 hour day.

Comment: Not able to understand what you sent

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51576/discussion-between-vinothbabu-and-user13763)

Comment: have a doubt how it takes 1000*60*60*24

Comment: for 1 hr it is 3600 s
then for 24 hrs it is 86400
and not 86400000

Comment: there is an issue in the code it accepts from date as 3rd May even if the current date is 29th